# Parameter Dependence Integrals

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity

Let $(X,\mathcal{X},\lambda)$ be a measure space and $(\Theta,d)$ a metric space.
Assume a function $f:X\times\Theta\to \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly bounded, meaning $\sup_{x\in X,\theta\in\Theta}|f(x,\theta)| < \infty$. Assume that
\begin{equation}
\Theta\ni\theta\mapsto\int_X f(x,\theta) \mathrm{d}\lambda(x) \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
is continuous. Is there any chance that the map $\theta \to f(\cdot,\theta)$ is also continuous, at least $\lambda$-a.s. ?